# Getting error "A potentially dangerous Request.Cookies value was detected from the client (Details= "<html><p align="cent...")"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http

I am getting the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Cookies value was detected from the client (Details= `<html><p align=cent...)`

from a Visual Studio 2010 VB.NET web application running on a server. The message occurs when a specific PC tries to access the application. Other PCs do not get this error when accessing the app. I have seen a lot of answers regarding Request.Forms, but not Request.Cookies. The PC getting the error is running Windows XP and IE 8. Does anyone have any suggestions of where I should be looking to resolve this message? Thank you.

Comment: I would also like to add that this error is sporadic. Sometimes the app works fine from this particular PC.

Comment: Apparently you write that on their cookies - find your bug. And clear that bad cookies.

Comment: Could you post what you are using to write to the cookie?

Comment: Are you using cookies to store personalisation details which are being saved as HTML to be rendered to the browser?

Comment: I am not writing any cookies...that's what is so confusing.

Comment: I had the user who gets this error clear their temp internet files and cookies and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default .NET behavior.
You should not send html to the cookie.

Available Options:

- `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`   in `<system.web>`
- Encrypt with any algorithm the content, thus breaking the html.
- Or remove the html